# Shebang not working when file executed directly from containing folder

Tags: php, bash, shebang

I am trying to run a function from a php file and run it from cli without having to type `php deploy` so have added a **shebang** so the cli knows how to run the script.

e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

if (PHP_SAPI !== 'cli') {
  echo 'bin/deployer must be run as a CLI application' . "\n";
  exit(1);
}

function deploy(){
  echo "Deploying" . "\n";
}

foreach ($argv AS $arg){
  function_exists($arg) AND call_user_func($arg);
}
```

> File: deployer

This does work fine from root directory and running `bin/deployer deploy` works as expected. I'm just curious as to why if run from the directory bin: `deployer deploy` i get `-bash: deployer: command not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in inside the `bin/` directory:

```
./deployer deploy
```

If you omit the `./` in front of your file, your shell will look for the command `deployer` in your path (`$PATH`), instead of treating it as a path to the file to execute.

The `$PATH` is a list of directories, where your shell will look for the command you typed.
To see what is in your path, try:

```
echo $PATH
```